# Objects have same hash, dictionary not recognizing as same

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

I have two objects which represent the same one. I even insured they had the same hash. I still got an error though from a dictionary:

```
>>> hash(one)
1098414562
>>> hash(one+zero)
1098414562
>>> a={one:1}
>>> a[one+zero]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    a[one+zero]
KeyError: {{|}|}
```

What else do I have to do to ensure the dictionary reconizes it as the same key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be properly [hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) dict keys, the objects must also define `__eq__()` or `__cmp__()`. They must compare equal to be recognized as the same key.

If the objects have the same hash, but do not compare equal, a hash collision is assumed, and they go separately in the same hash bucket.

When an object is looked up by hash, all objects in the matching hash bucket are compared to it, if none are equal, it's a KeyError.

Comment: I forgot the return statement in my `__eq__`.

Answer (score 2):

> If a class does not define a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either; if it defines `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable in hashed collections. If a class defines mutable objects and implements a `__cmp__()` or `__eq__()` method, it should not implement `__hash__()`, since hashable collection implementations require that a object’s hash value is immutable (if the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).

[source](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

Answer (score 0):

This is called a hash-collision. The hash is just a relatively efficient way to distribute the  keys across the dictionary. It doesn't guarantee uniqueness. When you look up a key, all the keys with a matching hash need to be considered, and will use the `__eq__` method to determine if they really match or not.

Aside:
It's possible to have a class that always returns the same hash for any of it's instances. However this destroys the usual `O(1)` lookup complexity

You can easily see the linear time lookups by experimenting with different values of `n` here

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(1)

d = {MyInt(i): i for i in xrange(n)}

d[MyInt(1)]  # This will take O(n) time since all values have the same hash
```